# How to get the open file limit in Java?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna, oshi

What options are available to get the (hard/soft) open file limits in java?

[OSHI supports getting the maximum amount of open file descriptors](https://www.oshi.ooo/oshi-core/apidocs/oshi/software/os/FileSystem.html) in its `FileSystem.getMaxFileDescriptors()` method but it mentions that `"There may be a lower per-process limit."`, which seems a bit too vague to me.

Another possiblity would be to use JNA or JNI to call [getrlimit()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html), which should get the open file limits of the JVM process. But I am a bit concerned if this will work on enough operating systems.

Are there other possiblities other than the mentioned ones above?

Comment: The easiest would be to provide a command line option to pass in the limit you want to use.  This wouldn't have to be the actual process limit, it could be some lower limit to conserve resources.  But if you really need a per-process limit I think wrangling a JNA call is your only option.

Comment: Maybe you wish to know how many files can you safely keep open in the same time? It is a different question as there can be other limitations not only ulimit.

Comment: I am mainly concerned about the max open files in regards to TCP connections which can be opened by the process and I am already aware of the other limitations around that like max ports, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux provides these values in [`/proc/sys/fs`](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.html)

> **file-max & file-nr**
> The value in file-max denotes the maximum number of file-handles that the Linux kernel will allocate. When you get lots of error messages about running out of file handles, you might want to increase this limit.
>
> **nr_open**
> This denotes the maximum number of file-handles a process can allocate. Default value is 1024*1024 (1048576) which should be enough for most machines. Actual limit depends on RLIMIT_NOFILE resource limit.

MacOS provides these values via sysctl:

```
kern.maxfiles: 245760
kern.maxfilesperproc: 122880
kern.num_files: 8685
```

FreeBSD also provides them via sysctl, but with a different name for the open files.

```
kern.maxfiles: 64534
kern.maxfilesperproc: 58077
kern.openfiles: 1339
```

OpenBSD also provides them via sysctl, and also with different names.

```
kern.maxfiles=7030
kern.nfiles=143
```

Solaris provides the values in `kstat:/kmem_cache/kmem_default/file_cache` for `buf_inuse` and `buf_max`.

On some Unix-based filesystem, you can probably capture the command line output of `lsof -nl` to count the current files (although this may be slow), and `ulimit -n` for the max.

OSHI returns the values from procfs for Linux, sysctl for macOS, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, kstat for Solaris, and from the command lines above for AIX.

I may be biased as OSHI's author, but that's probably your easiest route to getting these values cross-platform.

For Windows, there are no "file limits" per se.  Windows enforces limits on handles.  See [this Stack Exchange question](https://superuser.com/questions/1356320/what-is-the-number-of-open-files-limits) for more details on those limits.  That question and answer are the source of the qualified language I put in OSHI's javadocs.

> Theoretically in 64-bit Windows the maximum number of handles that a process can open is 2<sup>32</sup>, because handles have 32 significant bits. However in reality it has been limited to 16,777,216 (2<sup>24</sup>) per process. On 32-bit Windows the limit is likely 2<sup>16</sup>

and also

> However for a single process that uses the default C run-time libraries then the default limit is 512

and

> It's unclear the maximum number of total file handles for all processes in Windows

Comment: But is the OSHI way correct to get the open file limit for the process?
For example, when I use JNA to execute `getrlimit` to get the open file limit resource on Ubuntu 22.04 I get `1048576` as a hard limit, wheras OSHI returns `9223372036854775807` (which means unlimited).

Comment: I can also confirm that `/proc/{pid}/limits` returns the value of the JNA call as the hard limit -`1048576`.

Comment: @stackseti OSHI currently reports the systemwide limit.  On Linux that's `/proc/sys/fs/file-nr`.  The 1048576 is the per-process limit, `/proc/sys/fs/nr_open` which will match `getrlimit`.

Comment: So there is currently no way to get the per-process limit in OSHI?

Comment: @stackseti "Currently" -- no, but [I just added an issue to add that feature.](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/issues/2215)  Feel free to collaborate/contribute!